# Swiper renderExternal example in Virtual Slides with React

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Need to render a **Custom React component array** as **Virtual Slides** using `Swiper`.

Document says `renderExternal` can be used for this but there's no example in the API doc http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#virtual

Need to know on how this can be done using `renderExternal` function.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation got updated and now you can find [an example](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#virtual-example) of how to use it with React. For reference, here is the example that is given:

```
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm.bundle';

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      // dummy slides data
      slides: (function () {
        var slides = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 600; i += 1) {
          slides.push('Slide ' + (i + 1));
        }
        return slides;
      }()),
      // virtual data
      virtualData: {
        slides: [],
      },
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      // ...
      virtual: {
        slides: self.state.slides,
        renderExternal(data) {
          // assign virtual slides data
          self.setState({
            virtualData: data,
          });
        }
      },
    });
  }
  render() {
    {/* ... */}
    <div className="swiper-container">
      <div className="swiper-wrapper">
        {/* It is important to set "left" style prop on every slide */}
        {this.state.virtualData.slides.map((slide, index) => (
          <div className="swiper-slide"
            key={index}
            style={{left: `${virtualData.offset}px`}}
          >{slide}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* ... */}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's the best way to do it, but that is roughly how I did :

```
const mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  virtual: {
    slides: this.props.array (or this.state.array)
    renderExternal: function(data){}
  }
})
```

then you display your component in the template :

```
<div className="swiper-container">
  <div className="swiper-wrapper">
    <MyComponent
      myProps="mySwiper.virtual.slides[mySwiper.activeIndex]"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

(I did it with Vue, not React)